# while installing spring tools for eclipse error occuured

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-tools-4

I try to install Spring Tools from Eclipse marketplace.It is giving an error message at the end

**There are no licenses to review.  Either the software does not specify a license, or the license has already been reviewed and approved.**

Please help me to solve error

[image]

Comment: That just looks like information rather than an error - what happens when you press "Finish"?

Answer (score 0):

The message you're encountering is not actually an error but rather an informational message. When you click on "Finish" to initiate the installation process, Eclipse starts the download and installation of Spring Tools in the background. Here are some important points to consider:

Patience is Key: Depending on your internet speed and the size of the software, the installation process may take some time. It can vary from 10 to 35 minutes or even longer, so it's essential to be patient.

Don't Close Eclipse: It's crucial not to close the Eclipse application immediately after clicking "Finish." Closing Eclipse prematurely may interrupt the installation process.

Manual Progress Window: As depicted in the screenshot below, the "Progress" window within Eclipse doesn't automatically appear after clicking "Finish." You need to open it manually to monitor the installation progress.

[image: Progress Window in Eclipse while installing Spring Plugin]

At last you will get this window to restart eclipse.
[image]

[image]

I hope this clarifies the situation. The message you're seeing is part of the normal installation process, and by following these steps, you should be able to install Spring Tools successfully.